# iOS Swift: Swipe table cell to perform action (not reveal)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Recently I've been using Google's Inbox app, and I found the swipe to mark done/snooze feature very concise and useful. Since I have an app with a similar tableview interface in the works, I've been looking around for ways to implement this in iOS, but I haven't found anything. The closest I've gotten is swiping to reveal extra actions (as seen in the iOS Mail app), but that entails having to both swipe and click on a button, which is rather unwieldy. Is there a way to bundle an action into the swipe itself, instead of having it reveal some buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve that by implementing the method

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
```

in your delegate, respond with false and perform the feature when the function is called

Comment: I tried that out and although it no longer shows the delete button when swiped, I still have several questions: is it possible to detect swipe direction here, and can the swiping be animated? I'm planning on having two different actions, one performed on swiping left, the other performed on swiping right.